# "pay if you want to" using in app purchases (iphone)

Tags: iphone, app-store

I realise that you can't use in app purchases for real things. But does an in app purchase actually have to give extra functionality in the app. Can it be used to have optional paying?
I've made an app that really should be free but I'd like to make a little money even if it's only one 59p. So could I have an in app purchase which users can click to pay if they want to. it might sound stupid but I'm betting there is at least one person who would becase they are nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not use in app purchase for this sort of things. The reason is that you must sell a "virtual" good: this can be either a subscription to digital contents or "consumables", which you must interpret as additional functionalities that the user pays to unblock them.

I doubt that Apple will allow in app purchase for "donations". But this actually, would be nice: after all, if the user is willing to pay just to say thank you for developing this app, why not?

Comment: You could make it a "purchase" for some silly thing to get around that. Flair, if you will. :)

Comment: @ShaggyFrog, this is no longer true. I was able to get away with this with an app I submitted a few years back, but one more recently (within the last year) was rejected with the exact same setup. I was selling "badges" -- just visual "stickers" that told you how much you paid. That said, I've found a few apps that actually do employ the "pay what you want" model, and they are in the app store, one even approved recently. So... I don't know what the real trick is.